# localhost/phpmyadmin refused to connect

Tags: windows, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed xampp for php language but I encountered the problem on title above. I can't open localhost/phpmyadmin from the control panel.

Im using xampp v3.2.2 on OS windows 10

Comment: can you start the service in the control panel? you dont have another mysql or other app using port 3306, right?

Answer (score 0):

maybe another program app take your localhost port, so xampp cant run on 80. solution is change your port by edit **httpd.conf** file find **listen** and **ServerName** word and define specific port like 1337 or someting else.